# issue with loading .dll lib in C# code

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly

I have found a few posts about loading .dll libraries directly into C# projects through code. Here is the current code I am using:

```
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(dir + lib + ".dll"))
            {
                Assembly type = Assembly.LoadFrom(dir + lib + ".dll");
                object obj1 = type.CreateInstance(_namespace);



                assm.Add(obj1);
                return assm.Count - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dir + lib + ".dll: file does not exist");
                return -1;
            }
```

The code with:

```
                Assembly type = Assembly.LoadFrom(dir + lib + ".dll");
                object obj1 = type.CreateInstance(_namespace);
```

is suppose to locate the .dll file and load it as an instance then grabbing the class and creating an object from it. So I could make a library that has one function to print hello and I then load it into the code, I could then access that function by creating an Instance of the class. The problem is when I do the code:

```
                object obj1 = type.CreateInstance(_namespace);
```

obj1 is null, I know to give the namspace to the function (which I double checked and is correct), but no matter what it is always null. I checked to see if the Library is being loaded in as an assembly and it is! Here is the details of the assembly when I do a breakpoint (hovering over the object type):

```
    {ClassLibrary1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null}
```

Thank you in advance for your help, I am not sure what is wrong with my code.

Comment: So the assembly appears to be loaded correctly. How does `_namespace` look exactly, and how is your object declared?

Comment: _namespace is just a string with a value of the namespace of the library. the namespace in the library is: namespace ClassLibrary1 and _namespace is ClassLibrary1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is _namespace? It must contents full name of class (with namespace), for example `System.Collections.ArrayList`

Comment: yep I forgot to add the class on the end with the namespace, thank you!